# Why i'm getting OutOfMemoryException even if i release/dispose the Bitmap?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this class where i using the code to take screenshots:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScreenCapture
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureScreen()
        {
            return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up 
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            return img;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle"></param>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            using (Image img = CaptureWindow(handle))
            {
                img.Save(filename, format);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            using (Image img = CaptureScreen())
            {
                img.Save(filename, format);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {

            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
                int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int left;
                public int top;
                public int right;
                public int bottom;
            }

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

        }


    }
}
```

Then i have a new class i created where i'm using AviFile to create avi movie files from screenshots in real time:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AviFile;
using System.Drawing;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class ScreenshotsToAvi
    {
        int count = 0;
        VideoStream aviStream;
        AviManager aviManager;
        Bitmap bmp;

        public ScreenshotsToAvi()
        {
            aviManager = new AviManager(@"d:\testdata\new.avi", false);
        }

        public void CreateAvi(ScreenCapture sc)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bmp);
            }
            aviStream.AddFrame(bmp);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }

        public AviManager avim
        {
            get
            {
                return aviManager;
            }
            set
            {
                aviManager = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in form i use it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ScreenshotsToAvi screens2avi;
        int count;
        ScreenCapture sc;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            screens2avi = new ScreenshotsToAvi();
            label2.Text = "0";
            count = 0;
            sc = new ScreenCapture();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            sc.CaptureScreen();
            screens2avi.CreateAvi(this.sc);
            label2.Text = count.ToString();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            screens2avi.avim.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\screens7\");
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                File.Delete(filePath);
            label2.Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

After the program i running for about a minute or two it's getting to the ScreenShotsToAvi class and on this line throw the exception:

```
bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
```

Out of memory

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.ScreenshotsToAvi.CreateAvi(ScreenCapture sc) in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ScreenshotsToAvi.cs:line 26
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 41
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ReadWriteToMemory\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

And again im disposing the bmp all the time so why the exception is coming up ? Do i need to dispose anything else too ?

```
public void CreateAvi(ScreenCapture sc)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
            count++;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bmp);
            }
            aviStream.AddFrame(bmp);
            bmp.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error handling in the `System.Drawing` classes is frequently "Is it one of these 3 well known error codes? If not, I'll just report it via an OutOfMemoryException" - it may have *nothing* to do with memory. I've frequently found it's when the image format isn't one that GDI+ is actually happy with.

Comment: Very simply put, you're presumably running out of memory. You're adding the bitmaps to the avi. It's a good idea to dispose of the bitmaps as you're already doing, but keep in mind that they are still in use inside the avi file you're constructing. Until you generate that .avi file, you're basically constructing a list of bitmap images in memory.

Comment: Note that each tick of timer1, you're actually creating two images: the Image returned from `CaptureWindow` and the Bitmap you create from it.  You'll want to dispose both when you're done with them, but as @Flater points out, you may not be able to dispose of them until you write out your AVI.

Comment: adv12 and Flater and Damien maybe the solution is somehow to close the stream build the avi file exvery X seconds and then continue from the same point ?

Comment: Since this is `DrawImage` returning an OOM error code (which then gets mapped to an exception), it's quite likely that @Damien is correct and this isn't related to memory. GDI+ and `System.Drawing` are silly like that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long is your average recording? I attempted an eerily similar project only a few weeks ago, but the needed optimization to be able to parse video files on the fly without a noticeable memory/CPU footprint was just not worth it when you can buy a tool that does exactly that. It literally cost my employer more money for the time it took me to explain this to them, than they actually paid for the software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        bmp = new Bitmap(sc.CaptureScreen());
```

That's a Big Red Flag.  I'd assume that the CaptureScreen() method returns an Image or Bitmap object.  Then you make a *copy* of it for some reason.  And only dispose the copy, you do not dispose the original image that was returned by CaptureScreen().

That won't last long.

Assuming you actually need the copy (I have no idea why), you'll have to write it like this:

```
using (var img = sc.CaptureScreen())
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(img)) {
   // etc..
}
```

There are very few Image objects that are not actually a Bitmap.  Only a Metafile could be the other flavor, you won't get one from a screen-shot.  So do try:

```
using (var bmp = (Bitmap)sc.CaptureScreen()) {
   // etc..
}
```

Look at the VM size of your process in Task Manager to verify that your memory usage is now reasonably stable and no longer explodes.  You want to see it rapidly increase, then bounce up and down as the program keeps running.  The AVI encoder could be a resource hog as well if it doesn't stream the avi data directly to the file.  You *may* need to switch to 64-bit code if it requires too much memory.  Add the GDI Objects column in Task Manager, it reliably tells you if you are still leaking bitmap objects.